# XML parsing failure

Tags: java, android, xml, xml-parsing

I am writing an application for XML parser in android But when I download the code and run it, it runs perfectly ,
 But I wrote the same code but not working, Why so?

Is there any prerequisite for that? Please help me with this

**I am getting an error in `XMLParser.java`**

```
package com.xmlparser;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

import android.util.Log;

public class XMLParser {

    // constructor
    public XMLParser() {

    }

    /**
     * Getting XML from URL making HTTP request
     * @param url string
     * */
    public String getXmlFromUrl(String url) {
        String xml = null;

        try {
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            xml = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // return XML
        return xml;
    }

    /**
     * Getting XML DOM element
     * @param XML string
     * */
    public Document getDomElement(String xml){
        Document doc = null;
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        try {

            DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

            InputSource is = new InputSource();
                is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xml));
                doc = db.parse(is); 

            } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
                Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
                return null;
            } catch (SAXException e) {
                Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
                return null;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
                return null;
            }

            return doc;
    }

    /** Getting node value
      * @param elem element
      */
     public final String getElementValue( Node elem ) {
         Node child;
         if( elem != null){
             if (elem.hasChildNodes()){
                 for( child = elem.getFirstChild(); child != null; child = child.getNextSibling() ){
                     if( child.getNodeType() == Node.TEXT_NODE  ){
                         return child.getNodeValue();
                     }
                 }
             }
         }
         return "";
     }

     /**
      * Getting node value
      * @param Element node
      * @param key string
      * */
     public String getValue(Element item, String str) {     
            NodeList n = item.getElementsByTagName(str);        
            return this.getElementValue(n.item(0));
        }
}
```

My Log Cat

```
11-22 15:35:53.675: E/AndroidRuntime(19208): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.xmlparser/com.xmlparser.Xparser}: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
11-22 15:35:53.675: E/AndroidRuntime(19208):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2100)
11-22 15:35:53.675: E/AndroidRuntime(19208):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2125)
11-22 15:35:53.675: E/AndroidRuntime(19208):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:140)
11-22 15:35:53.675: E/AndroidRuntime(19208):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1227)
11-22 15:35:53.675: E/AndroidRuntime(19208):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-22 15:35:53.675: E/AndroidRuntime(19208):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-22 15:35:53.675: E/AndroidRuntime(19208):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
11-22 15:35:53.675: E/AndroidRuntime(19208):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-22 15:35:53.675: E/AndroidRuntime(19208):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-22 15:35:53.675: E/AndroidRuntime(19208):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1008)
11-22 15:35:53.675: E/AndroidRuntime(19208):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:775)
11-22 15:35:53.675: E/AndroidRuntime(19208):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-22 15:35:53.675: E/AndroidRuntime(19208): Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
11-22 15:35:53.675: E/AndroidRuntime(19208):    at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1118)

    11-22 15:19:21.500: E/AndroidRuntime(16631):    at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385)
    11-22 15:19:21.500: E/AndroidRuntime(16631):    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
    11-22 15:19:21.500: E/AndroidRuntime(16631):    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
    11-22 15:19:21.500: E/AndroidRuntime(16631):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:137)
    11-22 15:19:21.500: E/AndroidRuntime(16631):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
    11-22 15:19:21.500: E/AndroidRuntime(16631):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
    11-22 15:19:21.500: E/AndroidRuntime(16631):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
    11-22 15:19:21.500: E/AndroidRuntime(16631):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:670)
    11-22 15:19:21.500: E/AndroidRuntime(16631):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:509)
    11-22 15:19:21.500: E/AndroidRuntime(16631):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
    11-22 15:19:21.500: E/AndroidRuntime(16631):    at com.xmlparser.XMLParser.getXmlFromUrl(XMLParser.java:45)
    11-22 15:19:21.500: E/AndroidRuntime(16631):    at com.xmlparser.Xparser.onCreate(Xparser.java:37)
    11-22 15:19:21.500: E/AndroidRuntime(16631):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5206)
    11-22 15:19:21.500: E/AndroidRuntime(16631):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
    11-22 15:19:21.500: E/AndroidRuntime(16631):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2064)
```

this is my Xparser.java

```
package com.xmlparser;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Xparser extends ListActivity {
    static final String URL = "http://api.androidhive.info/pizza/?format=xml";
    // XML key nodes
    static final String KEY_ITEM = "item";
    static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
    static final String KEY_COST = "cost";
    static final String KEY_DESC = "description";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_xmlparser);
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> menuItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
        String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL);// getting XML
        Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml);// getting Dom Element

        NodeList n1 = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_ITEM);
         // looping through all item nodes <item>
        for(int i=0 ; i < n1.getLength(); i++){
            HashMap<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
            Element e = (Element) n1.item(i);
            //adding each child to Hashmap node key
            map.put(KEY_ID, parser.getValue(e,KEY_ID));
            map.put(KEY_NAME, parser.getValue(e,KEY_NAME));
            map.put(KEY_COST, "Rs."+ parser.getValue(e,KEY_COST));
            map.put(KEY_DESC, parser.getValue(e,KEY_DESC));

             // adding HashList to ArrayList
            menuItems.add(map);
        }

    // Adding menuItems to ListView
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, menuItems,
                R.layout.list_select_item,
                new String[] { KEY_NAME, KEY_DESC, KEY_COST }, new int[] {
                        R.id.name, R.id.desciption, R.id.cost });
    setListAdapter(adapter);


    // selecting single ListView item
    ListView lv = getListView();
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String name = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name)).getText().toString();
        String cost = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.cost)).getText().toString();
        String desc = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.desciption)).getText().toString();

        Intent in = new Intent();
        in.putExtra(KEY_NAME, name);
        in.putExtra(KEY_DESC, desc);
        in.putExtra(KEY_COST, cost);
        startActivity(in);
    }

    });
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.xmlparser, menu);
        return true;
        }
}
```

Comment: Please add what's not working. Are you running in exceptions? Is there a stacktrace?

Comment: You need to post the errors you get.

Comment: what error you got??'

Comment: I am getting error at this line
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

Comment: Please post the stacktrace of the exception!

Comment: U mean this???? catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (IOException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }

Comment: No I mean the exception you see in your stacktrace, if you get one. Do you see an exception stacktrace in your log?

Comment: No I have added almost complete Error log here....

Comment: Check your host url also Internet permission in manifest file

Comment: i have added Internt permission in manifest file

Comment: @Shrinivas Post Your `Xparser.java`

Comment: Please check I have added Xparser.java

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The exception [tells you everything](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html) you need to know. You are trying to submit data on the main thread. Do the networking operations in a separate thread.

[There's a link in the docs that explains it](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-anr.html), and [this might help you to move on](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html).

Comment: I am still learning , I dont know much , could you please help me with this, i didnt even get the error, Sorry :(

Comment: I added another link, it's everything you need. Look specifically at "Perform Network Operations on a Separate Thread".

Comment: But I have one more project which is same way I have done But that file is running, why so?????

Comment: Please actually look at my links! You would have seen this: `This is only thrown for applications targeting the Honeycomb SDK or higher. Applications targeting earlier SDK versions are allowed to do networking on their main event loop threads, but it's heavily discouraged.` Maybe your other project targets a different SDK.

Comment: Ok yes, You are absolutely correct, Thanks a lot, I removed the Target sdk line and its working, Can you please provide me with the link where I can create a separate thread for that or such Example where Target SDK is honeycomb or more??? Thanks

Comment: The last link in my answer already shows you a great example. :) Like I said, look specifically at the section "Perform Network Operations on a Separate Thread".

Comment: I know i am asking silly questions, I read tht and understood, But i need help I have to add String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL);// getting XML
  Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml);// getting Dom Element
  
  NodeList n1 = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_ITEM);
   // looping through all item nodes <item>
  for(int i=0 ; i < n1.getLength(); i++){
   HashMap<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
   Element e = (Element) n1.item(i);
   these lines to AsyncTask right?

Comment: This is beyond this question and especially too much for comments. Please ask a new specific question if you need continuous help.